# How to configure Mercury Mail Transport System for Zend Server?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-server, mercury-mta

I have just installed Mercury Mail Transport System 4.73, along with Zend Server 6. I wonder what configurations need to be done in order for me to use the mail() function in PHP. I can see that in php.ini, SMTP has been set to localhost and smtp_port has been set to 25. But when I tested the mail() function in PHP, it returned a false value and failed to send an email.

Besides Mercury Mail Transport System, what other mail servers would be recommended?